# Finite Element Analysis of flow along a cylinder

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, fluid-statics, simulations

[image]

Is there a mathematical iteration formula (known as finite element analysis that can investigate the flow perpendicular to the curved surface of cylinder? I am wondering what type of iteration method do SolidWorks software uses to compute these flow.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for this software? Usually these types of details are mentioned there (though, occasionally by pointing to some technical document)

Comment: @KyleKanos, ok, but are there any finite element method that is simple to understand that you know on calculating these fluid flow?

Comment: I've never really worked with FEM, only FVM/FDM. I would assume textbooks on the subject would have simple descriptions, but I honestly don't know.

Comment: @KyleKanos, oh i see, I believe FVM is for fluid and FEM is for structural, and since you worked in this field, do you know how FVM calculated the values in the software u use?

Comment: We used [MUSCL scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUSCL_scheme) for much of our work.